# Socket.io and Express. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

i started my project without socket.io initially and everything is working fine until i modified my program use socket.io.

Node v8.4.0

Socket.io v2.0.3

Express v4.15.4

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

/* other settings for my app */

let server = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3001);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('test', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
});
```

When my client did a GET request, i received this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
info    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/zac/Desktop/socket/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:730:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/zac/Desktop/socket/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/zac/Desktop/socket/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:256:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/zac/Desktop/socket/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at panelRights (/Users/zac/Desktop/socket/bin/index.js:488:30)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/zac/Desktop/socket/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/zac/Desktop/socket/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jsonwebtoken___default.a.verify (/Users/zac/Desktop/socket/bin/index.js:429:11)
    at /Users/zac/Desktop/socket/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:27:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

i went to the code where the error is pointing

> at panelRights (/Users/zac/Desktop/socket/bin/index.js:488:30)

```
panelRights(req, res, next) {
    if (req.decoded && req.decoded._id) {
      let _id = req.decoded._id;
      Panel.findById({_id: _id}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).send({
            success: false,
            error: 'Unauthorized.'
          });
        }
        if (result.role === 'panel') {
          req.decodedUser = result;
          next();
        } else {
          return res.status(401).send({
            success: false,
            error: 'Unauthorized.'
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).send({
        success: false,
        error: 'Unauthorized.'
      });
    }
  }
```

error pointing to **else {
          return res.status(401).send({** the last return status after else.

I have no issue with these code without socket.io, they only occurs after. Any advice on how to overcome this would be nice. Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Zac, Can you please update your post with the version of your `Node.js`, `socket.io` and `express.js` ?

Comment: @DavidR hello David, the version number is listed at the top of the post.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that